# JFugue parser exception in the value of duration, in the case of 'notes sharing same duration'

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi, jfugue

I'm working with [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/) , when i tried to execute the code

```
Player myPlayer = new Player();
myPlayer.play( ":DEFAULT(duration=.25)");  
Pattern test=new Pattern(" m327.0  m348.8  ( m392.4/0.25  m413.393 m392.4 )/0.5 m348.8 ");
myPlayer.play(test);
```

I'm getting a Parser exception,The character, parsed as a note velocity, is not recognized: : 0

when i remove the 0 from ')/0.5' , it works properly

```
Pattern test=new Pattern(" m327.0  m348.8  ( m392.4/0.25  m413.393 m392.4 )/.5 m348.8 ");
```

The same exception is showing for all values greater than or equal to 1(for eg: ')/1.5' ) 
But, I noticed that  m392.4/0.25 is working without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
( m392.4/0.25  m413.393 m392.4 )/.5
```

When JFugue parses elements in parentheses, it adds whatever immediately follows the parentheses to each element within the parentheses. In this case, the JFugue parser adds `/.5` to each of the microtone elements, giving:

```
m392.4/0.25/0.5 m413.393/0.5 m392.4/0.5
```

Look at that first token. `m392.4/0.25/0.5` is not valid; it contains two durations, and JFugue does not know how to interpret this. After successfully parsing the first duration (`/0.25`), the JFugue parser is now expecting to either see a velocity, a connector (like `+` or `_`), or nothing. The error message does seem misleading, so I'll look into that.

Comment: Thank you David for helping me to find the problem... I know that there is no one other than you  to give the solution.. Thank you very much...  and Good luck...